# How to post data using curl and get reponse based on posted data

Tags: php, curl

Here is my code to `POST` data:

```
<?php
$data = array("account" => "1234", "dob" => "30051987", "site" => "mytestsite.com");
$data_string = json_encode($data);

$url = 'http://mydomain.com/curl.php';

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))
);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$json_result = json_decode($result, true);
?>

<p>Your confirmation number is: <strong><?php echo $json_result['ConfirmationCode']; ?></strong></p>
```

Whereas on domain/server **curl.php** file code as under:

```
<?php
// header 
header("content-type: application/json");

if($_POST):
    echo json_encode(array('ConfirmationCode' => 'somecode'));
else:
    echo json_encode(array('ConfirmationCode' => 'none'));
endif;
?>
```

But it always return `'none'`. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function on [this link](http://bavotasan.com/2011/post-url-using-curl-php/) will work.

```
    <?php

function post_to_url($url, $data) {
    $fields = '';
    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
        $fields .= $key . '=' . $value . '&';
    }
    rtrim($fields, '&');

    $post = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_POST, count($data));
    curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
    curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    $result = curl_exec($post);

    curl_close($post);
    return $result;
}

$data = array(
    "name" => "new Name",
    "website" => "http://bavotasan.com",
    "twitterID" => "bavotasan"
);

$surl = 'http://mydomain.com/curl.php';
echo post_to_url($surl, $data);
?>
```

Whereas, on **`curl.php`**

```
<?php
file_put_contents('abc.text', "here is my data " . implode('->', $_POST));
if ($_POST['name']):
    print_r($_POST['name']);
endif;
?>
```

Answer (score 17):

The actual problem is in grabbing it..

```
<?php
 $data = array("account" => "1234", "dob" => "30051987", "site" => "mytestsite.com");
 $data_string = json_encode($data);

 $url = 'http://mydomain.com/curl.php';

 $ch = curl_init($url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
                     'Content-Type: application/json',
                 'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))
   );
  $result = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);

  echo $result;

  //$json_result = json_decode($result, true);
 ?>
```

your code for curl.php

```
<?php
 $fp = fopen('php://input', 'r');
 $rawData = stream_get_contents($fp);

 echo "<pre>";
 print_r($rawData);
 echo "</pre>";


 /*if($rawData):
 echo json_encode(array('ConfirmationCode' => 'somecode'));;
 else:
 echo json_encode(array('ConfirmationCode' => 'none'));
 endif;*/

 ?>
```

Since You are sending the data as raw JSON in the body, it will not populate the $_POST variable

Hope this will help you

Comment: Still getting the same result .i.e. none

Comment: yes it is working, but how would check if data is posted or how would i varify the posted data? Like account and site parameters etc ?

Comment: ok I am editing code for it once again.. have a look.You can use print_r($rawData) in curl.php and then echo the curl result in your main file

Answer (score 2):

The "correct" `Content-Type` header for a POST request should be `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, but you overrode it with `application/json` (which is only needed from the server side).

Change your code to below:

```
<?php
$data = array("account" => "1234", "dob" => "30051987", "site" => "mytestsite.com");
$data_string = json_encode($data);

$url = 'http://mydomain.com/curl.php';

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true); // no need to use custom request method

// ----- METHOD #1: no need to "stringify"
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_array);
// ----- METHOD #2: or if you really like to JOSN-ify
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array("json"=>$data_string));

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
/* ------ this will be handled by PHP/cURL
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))
);
*/
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$json_result = json_decode($result, true);
?>
```

Comment: I doubt if my code on server is correct that is curl.php code?

Comment: @atif If your `curl.php` is as simple as you post, it's correct (except the extra `;` in line 5).

Comment: It is still returning none mean it goes in else condition, and that symbol ; is a typo error here not in code :)

Comment: @atif Try to add `curl_setopt($ch,CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT,true)` and then `print_r(curl_getinfo($ch))` after `curl_exec` to see if something's wrong. Also `print_r($_POST)` in `curl.php` to help debug.

Comment: print_r(curl_getinfo($ch)) this prints a long array , but print_r($_POST) prints nothing

Comment: @atif `print_r(curl_getinfo($ch))` should tell you what request header cURL actually used. Did you see something unexpected?

Comment: Nopx, everything seems fine to me, but `@file_get_contents('php://input')` seems to return something at least.